# Is ' Sky children of light' a halal game?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, game

This game contains music just like other games but can be turned off . It contains many spirits (spirits that resemble human appearance) and the spirits are required to get relieved/saved by players . After those spirits are saved ,by offering the spirits some candles players can get costumes and many cosmetics such as mask , capes , hairstyles, instruments ,etc. For this ,players need to fly with their friends and collect many candles  from many beautiful places , temples (no statues inside temples), they dont tell players to worship anything . Sometimes quests appear to meditate and write our thoughts  which other players can see. Weekly players are reborn after they attend to hell like zone named Eden where statues of dead kids are given lights from the player's collection meanwhile the player is stoned from sky .after giving all lights to statues,player dies too and is reborn after flying in space and getting candles from spirits floating in space . The game cycle continues this way
One of my religious friend said this game is indirectly shirk after hearing players need to offer candles to spirit for getting items  . Ive stopped playing it after hearing this although I'm not sure if this game really is shirk or not. I only go in the game to return the promised amount of hearts to a nonmuslim in-game-friend who bought me adventure pass to unlock more items . When i told my religious friend about this , she said promise made in sins should not be fulfilled And to tell her(the game friend) directly everything .
Also Many of my close friends are still playing it . They say they dont feel its shirk as they take this 'spirit item exchanging thing' as buying items from seller and it has nothing to do with their belief in Allah . So my question is , does this fall into shirk or not ? Sorry for this long question and may Allah reward you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I just read a fatwah stating that any actions made in the gaming environment (by players or characters) attributed to Allah SWT, are haram. Here it is:

1. https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/341431/games-about-characters-with-supernatural-or-magical-powers
2. https://islamqa.org/hanafi/fatwa-ca/121659

Also, the nature of the gaming lifestyle can be considered haram due to the excessive time spent which is considered wasteful. Time should be spent praising Allah SWT and better understanding what Allah has commanded us and in self-development and of being of service to one another. There are many blessings received by Allah SWT that we can't know but some include our heartbeat, breath, millions of cellular reactions in our body, the sun, fresh air, water, food which are all offered for our use and enjoyment whether or not we are a righteous person. There are no blessings given for gaming, wasting time, laziness, and excessive sleep for example. The better use of time is to be His willing slave. Go to help someone, donate your time, work to make a donation to a cause you believe in. Learn a new skill. Exercise and take care of our health. There are more rewarding ways to spend time. Shaytan must be the author of these games that steer us away from the path of Allah SWT. Surely evil is like cancer. Submerge yourself in prayer for strength and clarity; Make dua. Ask HIM for guidance. For, Allah knows best.